# Clicking on LI link using Selenium Webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

New to Selenium here. Thanks for the help in advance!

I'm try to click on a li href inside an unordered list.  Here is that unordered list.

```
<ul id="search_result"> 
    <li>1.  <a href="https://www.bookseriesinorder.com/lee-child/" rel="bookmark" 
             title="Permanent Link to Lee Child">Lee Child</a>
    <li>2.  <a href="https://www.bookseriesinorder.com/eileen-brady/" rel="bookmark" 
             title="Permanent Link to Eileen Brady">Eileen Brady</a>
    <li>3.  <a href="https://www.bookseriesinorder.com/lyla-lee/" rel="bookmark" 
             title="Permanent Link to Lyla Lee">Lyla Lee</a>
</ul>
```

And here is the code I'm trying to use.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal' # normal, eager, none
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.bookseriesinorder.com/")

# Add code to wait until the search box has been loaded
try:
    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "s")))
except:
    driver.quit()    

# Enter the text to search for
author = "Lee Child"
search.send_keys(author)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Find the author link and click it
try:
    # search_results = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    #     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[@id='search_result']")))
    # search_results = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    #     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[@id='search_result']/a[contains(@href, 'lee-child')]"))).click    
    search_results = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[@id='search_result']/a[contains(@href, 'lee-child')]")))        
except:
    driver.quit()    

print (search_results)
driver.close()
```

I am trying to click on the link for Lee Child.  I am trying to use XPATH and I can find the ul if I don't include the list item.  But when I try to add the list item (so the search for Lee Child) I get the error "NameError: name 'search_results' is not defined".

Can anyone explain what the correct XPATH should be to find the link for Lee Child?

Thanks in advance for any and all guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.
the only problem with your code is the XPath of the link you trying to click.
The `a` element is not a direct child of `ul`, so it should be `//` there, not `/`.
Also, it is preferably to use `element_to_be_clickable` rather than `presence_of_element_located`.
So, instead of

```py
search_results = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[@id='search_result']/a[contains(@href, 'lee-child')]")))
```

please try this:

```py
search_results = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[@id='search_result']//a[contains(@href, 'lee-child')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Great! I'm happy I could help you :)